# Trying to use PiGRRL 2.0 Custom Gamepad PCB but there's no documentation on how to program the buttons

Tags: gpio, pi-3, retropie, gamepad

I have this gamepad PCB from Adafruit: https://www.adafruit.com/products/3015

In their guide it's supposed to work with the file they give you but that image only works on raspberry pi 2 and I'm using a raspberry pi 3 so I can't use that image on my sd card. How do I figure out which GPIO pins the buttons are on? and then set those up to work on my raspberry pi 3?

UPDATE: 
Here's the image of the Adafruit PiGRRL Gamepad PCB @MohammadAli added in the comments to help

[image: Adafruit Gamepad PCB]

Comment: Here is a page were you can download the schematics for the game pad PCb: https://oshpark.com/shared_projects/i2TaIEic

Comment: what's the best app to view the schematic files? @MohammadAli

Comment: CadSoft EAGLE which is the native .brd format viewer. http://3dbrdviewer.cytec.bg/board should also work fine for you, just be sure to flip the board over to see the other half of the traces.

Comment: here is a decent image of the circuit that I've uploaded: http://anonymous.codes/static/ADAFRUITPI_WIRING_DIAGRAM.png

Comment: What programming language were you hoping to use to interface with the  game pad?, maybe I can write a bit of sample code today or tomorrow if I get the time

Comment: I'm not sure. This is my first time making something like this. The buttons are wired to GPIO pins through the ribbon cable plugged into the PiTFT and then into the Rasp Pi 3. I basically used this guide with everything the same except I used a Raspberry Pi3 instead of a Pi 2. https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-2/overview I would have just used their image for the Rasp Pi but it says theirs only works on a Pi 2.

Comment: Are the pins 1:1 from the pi to the PCb or is the tft plug moving any of the pins around? The image I shared above should allow you to identify which pins are connected to which buttons, all you need to do from there is to follow the ribbon cable to the Pi and see which pin each button is connected to and write that down.

Comment: I did that by entering the buttons in retrogame.c file but maybe I need to also double check the soldering I did. None of the buttons seem to work still.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but Did you compile and run by using 'make retrogame' 'sudo mv retrogame /usr/local/bin' 'sudo reboot'

Comment: I did @MohammadAli

Comment: Can you please list which buttons that you believe are mapped to which gpio pins. Just as a table would be fine

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the button mapping I'm using: http://imgur.com/wEx1D5m @MohammadAli

Comment: Was using this guide for help: https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-2/software

Comment: Do any of the buttons on the tft display or the shoulder buttons work? I'm taking a test right now but I'll write a test script for you when I get home to see weather it's a hardware or software problem. Do you have a programming language of preference? Basically C or Python are your options as those are the only languages that I really understand

Comment: is it possible for you to plug the pi directly into the gamepad with a ribbon cable to rule out any other possible problems?

Comment: Yeah. I'll have to take it apart and try that. I just remembered, at one point the Pitft buttons next the screen worked at one point and one would shutdown the pi when pressed. Now they it does nothing after installing a new image on the sd card so I know those at least should working hardware-wise.

Comment: You do realize that the button mapping is only applied when the tft screen is disconnected and the pi is connected either by hdmi or over composite to an external display

Comment: OMG I see what you mean. No I didn't. How are the buttons supposed to work with the TFT screen then?

Comment: The same file has a ioTFT[] section. I'm going to try that.

Comment: Here is a table i went through the trouble of making. https://anonymous.codes/static/ADAFRUIT-GAMEPAD-WIRING-TABLE.png It matches the adafruit tutorial table exactly because the pi 2b + and 3 have the exact same gpio. I'm working on writing you a step by step tutorial, check back here in 15-25 minutes, to click that accepted answer button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We start our adventure by installing an os onto our pi, this will require a minimum 4gb micro sd card. Click the download link that says "Raspberry Pi 2/3" Now after the image has downloaded, burn it to an sd card. If you do not know how, please google it their are a lot of tutorials on it and seeing that you were able to burn an img file before I'm not going to go over it.
2. connect your raspberry pi to an HDMI or composite display and plug in a usb keyboard and mouse. Be sure to disconnect everything from your gpio pins before booting as the pi is only capable of driving a single display.
3. boot the pi
4. On first boot the system will ask you to configure an input device. it really doesn't matter which keys you use here as long as you remember them.
5. press `f4` on your keyboard to exit Emulationstation and to enter the command line.
6. Now we will preform some basic system optimization/configuration. Enter `sudo rasps-config`into your terminal then press enter.
7. in the prompt use your keyboard arrow keys to go to `Advanced options` then press enter.
8. Inside Advanced options Set the following:

   1. Enable `SPI`(Serial Peripheral Interface)
      2.Disable `Overscan`(because your tft display does not have an overscan)
   2. Enable `Device Tree`
      4.Force 3.5mm headphone jack for `audio`(because hdmi will be disconnected when you are using your tft display)
9. Reboot your pi using `sudo shutdown` to shutdown completely. Only remove the power after all green led activity has ceased.
10. First we’ll install fbcp (a live framebuffer mirroring tool) using directions from [HERE](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/Framebuffer-use#framebuffer-mirroring)

    ```
    sudo apt-get install cmake
    git clone https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp
    cd rpi-fbcp/
    mkdir build
    cd build/
    cmake ..
    make
    sudo install fbcp /usr/local/bin/fbcp
    ```

    (You do not need to actually use the link or read any of it because all of the install code is above)
11. Now we will edit the boot file to allow fbcp to launch on boot the boot file is located at `/etc/rc.local` you may edit it by using `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` Before the last line that says `exit 0` you want to insert the following `/usr/local/bin/fbcp &` which will launch fbcp on boot. Now save the changes and exit by using the keyboard shortcut `control x`
12. Now edit the file `/boot/config.txt` and add the following 4 lines.

    ```
    hdmi_force_hotplug=1 #Pretends HDMI hotplug signal is asserted so it appears a HDMI display is attached
    hdmi_group=1 #defines the HDMI type as DMT
    hdmi_mode=87 #defines screen resolution in CEA or DMT format 87 being custom
    hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0 # sets the following in the following order: hdmi_cvt=<width> <height> <framerate> <aspect> <margins> <interlace> <rb>
    ```
13. with the file still open you will need to add one of the following lines to the end of the file depending on wether your display touchscreen is resistive or capacitive.

    For capacitative touchscreen use:

    ```
    dtoverlay=pitft28-capacitive-overlay,rotate=90,speed=80000000,fps=60
    ```

    For resistive touch screens use:

    ```
    dtoverlay=pitft28-resistive-overlay,rotate=90,speed=80000000,fps=60
    ```

    For tft displays that do not support touch either line will work.

    Note: that `dtoverlay` is a Device Tree function that is used to enable the SPI driver.
14. Now when you save and reboot HDMI will probably not work on all monitors, and it is recommended that you disconnect the HDMI display before attempting to use the tft one.
15. If you don’t already have the PiTFT assembled and connected, do that now.
16. Now only one more piece of software called retrogame lets you connect buttons directly to the Raspberry Pi’s GPIO header and simulates key presses. It can be downloaded from the command line using:

    ```
    git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Retrogame
    ```
17. Enter the directory by using the following command:

    ```
    cd Adafruit-Retrogame
    ```
18. Edit the file `retrogame.c` by using the command below:

    ```
    sudo nano retrogame.c
    ```
19. A full list of available key codes can be found at `/usr/include/linux/input.h`
20. look for the table called `ioStandard` i know that it says for HDMI only, but because we are using that `fbcp` software that we installed before. The pi actually thinks that it is outputting over HDMI in an attempt to trick it into using gpu based hardware acceleration.  Your IoStandard table should look like the one below:

Note: depending on your display, modifying the IOTFT table may be the right thing to do.(advised by  @jimmyplaysdrums) just try both and see what works for you.

```
    ioStandard[] = { 
    // This pin/key table is used when the PiTFT isn't found 
    // (using HDMI or composite instead), as with our original 
    // retro gaming guide. 
    // Input Output (from /usr/include/linux/input.h) 
    { 4,  KEY_LEFT     }, // Joystick (4 pins) 
    { 19, KEY_RIGHT    }, 
    { 16, KEY_UP       }, 
    { 26, KEY_DOWN     }, 
    { 14, KEY_LEFTCTRL }, // A/Fire/jump/primary/RED
    { 15, KEY_LEFTALT  }, // B/Bomb/secondary/YELLOW 
    { 20, KEY_Z        }, // X/BLUE 
    { 18, KEY_X        }, // Y/GREEN 
    {  5, KEY_SPACE    }, // Select 
    {  6, KEY_ENTER    }, // Start 
    { 12, KEY_A        }, // L Shoulder 
    { 13, KEY_S        }, // R Shoulder 
    { 17, KEY_ESC      }, // Exit ROM PiTFT Button 1
    { 22, KEY_1        }, // PiTFT Button 2
    { 23, KEY_2        }, // PiTFT Button 3
    { 27, KEY_3        }, // PiTFT Button 4
```

21. After editing, compile and run the code with:

    ```
    make retrogame
    sudo mv retrogame /usr/local/bin
    ```
22. To make retrogame start on boot as we did before open the `/etc/rc.local` file using the command below.

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/rc.local
    ```
23. now before the final `exit 0` line insert the line below, then save and exit.

    ```
    /usr/local/bin/retrogame &
    ```
24. Now only one more step until your on your way, its so that Emulationstsation recognizes retrogame as a keyboard. All you need to do is open the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-retrogame.rules` using the command

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-retrogame.rules
    ```
25. Then copy and paste the line below into the new file:

    ```
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="retrogame", ENV{ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD}="1"
    ```

    Then save and close this file then reboot.
26. Enjoy! and be sure to post any problems you receive in the comments and I will try and debug with you.

Comment: Ok. Good news and bad news. First, the pin/key table didn't work in the ioStandard section but when I added it to the ioTFT section the buttons started to work! (this is with the TFT screen attached and no HDMI screen attached btw). Second, all the buttons seem to work except for the UP on the D-pad and the Y button. It could be a hardware issue since I double checked the correct pins are chosen in the table (16 and 18). I'll keep you updated after I take it apart again.

Comment: Ohh, ok cool I'll make that an edit, right now.

Comment: Not a problem man, always glad to help!

Comment: It's most likely a hardware issue, be sure to check the cables too, for any bent or missing pins

Comment: Also make sure that you've installed the buttons in the correct orientation, I've seen way too many people solder the wrong  two pins and end up with a button that's always on or always off.