# Running Retropie on LCD

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I'm a beginner and just got my Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I also ordered the Kuman 3.5" LCD TFT screen that runs off the pins with my Pi. I have the drivers for the screen that comes with a modified version of Raspbian and it runs just fine. But I actually got the screen so I can make a mobile emulation station that I can take on the go, however the screen won't work when I have Retropie with the drivers for the LCD screen. Whenever I connect directly to the Pi with my tv through HDMI it works just fine. Is there a way I can transfer the display to go to the LCD automatically?

Comment: Here are some possibly useful links ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjdFmg5xwTI, https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=95366, http://blog.petrockblock.com/forums/forum/retropie-project-forum/video-output-on-retropie/, https://hackaday.io/project/6157-retropie-with-a-22-lcd-screen

Comment: None of these worked sorry

Comment: Here is a very similar problem just skip the parts that tak about the game pad and it should work out ok: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46735/trying-to-use-pigrrl-2-0-custom-gamepad-pcb-but-theres-no-documentation-on-how

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue a while ago, I read something about LCD's which connect to the Pi over GPIO use special kernels, and require drivers along with certain graphics processing to work, mainly relating to OpenGL.

In the end, I just purchased http://www.dx.com/p/2-ch-video-input-3-5-tft-lcd-display-monitor-module-w-cable-black-silvery-grey-ntsc-pal-201631#.V-MtXZN96Ho which uses RCA video, and works fine with retropie.

Though, have you tried enabling SPI within `raspi-config`, or commenting out the line `blacklist spi-bcm2708` in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`?

Hope this helps!